# How to automate an EX command in vim?

Tags: vim, ex

I have an EX command that I use pretty regularly to remove multi-line comments.

```
:%s,/\*\_.\{-}\*/\n,,g
```

Is there any way I can make it an EX alias (if such a thing exists?) in vimrc file?

The goal would be something like:

```
:nocomments
```

Then it would run that regex search and replace. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The relevant help is `:help usr_40.txt` entitled 'Make New Commands'.

Just put either of the below options in your .vimrc to make it permanent.

#### 40.1 Defining command-line commands

For your question you can do this (note that user defined commands must begin with a capital
letter):

`command! Nocomments :%s,/\*\_.\{-}\*/\n,,g`

#### 40.2 Key mapping

You can also define custom normal mode commands with `nmap and nnoremap`:

`nnoremap <LEADER>n :%s,/\*\_.\{-}\*/\n,,g<CR>`

Then in normal mode you can press your leader key (default is `\` unless you
remapped it) followed by the letter `n` and the substitute command will happen
(note the carriage return had to be added).

Comment: You just made my life a lot easier thanks, will use that command! thing over and over. Thanks!

Comment: @Ted glad it helped - I added a second option (creating a custom mapping) in case you prefer that way.